# How to update SQL from DataTable, without select query in DataAdaper initializing

Tags: c#, datatable, sql-update, dataadapter, sqldataadapter

I have application, which loading data from CSV to DataTable and from this populated DataTable it inserting data to MS SQL.

I found some note how to make an update, but I´m looking for the way how to avoid selecting in initializing of DataAdapter:

```
conn_update.Open();

string sql_q = "@"SELECT * FROM [publicDB].[dbo].[customers]"

SqlDataAdapter SQLUpdateAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql_q, conn_update);

cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(SQLUpdateAdapter);

cmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();

 SQLUpdateAdapter.Update(treti);
```

First question:

Is there any way to do this update, without using Select Command when initializing SQL DataAdapter?

From this

> SqlDataAdapter SQLUpdateAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(**sql_q**,
>   conn_update);

To something like this (just example, for a solution I want to find)

```
 SqlDataAdapter SQLUpdateAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(conn_update);
```

Or another way how to avoid meaningless selecting form DB?

Second (stupid) question: What is the purpose for using SqlCommandBuilder :

```
cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(SQLUpdateAdapter);

cmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
```

Thaks a lot for your answer!

Comment: Filling the table from a csv is going to make them all inserts unless you select the records first, then change them with the input from the csv. Given what you've stated I'm not sure I'd have bothered with a datatable.

Answer (score 1):

To Question #2:

The `SqlCommandBuilder` generate automatically TSQL-Queries to update single Tables related to your DataSet. This is necessary because the `SqlDataAdapter` didn't generate queries that matching changes between the `DataSet` and the SQL Server Instance. `SqlCommandBuilder` also registering himself as a Listener to the `RowUpdating` Event.